# How to Bind two class in Datatable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I have a problem with binding two java classes to one Datatable component.
I have two managed beans Product and Order

Product source:

```
public class Product {

    private Integer id;
    private String kategoria;
    private String symbol;
    private String opis;
    private Double cena;

    //getters and setters
    //.....
    //hashCode, equals methods

}
```

and Order source:

```
public class Order {

    private Product produkt;
    private Integer quantity;   

    public Order() {}

    public Order(Product product, Integer quantity) {
        this.produkt = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    public void setProduct(Product produkt) {
        this.produkt = produkt;
    }

    public Product getProdukt() {
        return produkt;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

my question is: how to bind this class `Order` to `<h:dataTable />` component to have Poduct values and quantity numer. I have created ProductBean class with setOrder and getOrder methods

```
public List<OrderLine> getList() {
    List<OrderLine> l = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();
    for(OrderLine ol : list) {
        l.add(ol);
    }
    return l;
}

public void setList(Set<OrderLine> list) {
    if (this.list.isEmpty() )
        this.list = list;
    else {
        Iterator<OrderLine> it = this.list.iterator();
        for(OrderLine p : list) {
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                if(it.next().equals(p)) {
                    this.list.add(p);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing a conversion from the set to the list, because I thought it would be more convenient to retrieve data from a list.

Comment: You show `Product`, `Order` and `OrderLine` classes. Where is your managed bean? Assuming that your managed bean contains these `getList` and `setList` methods, how's the relation between `OrderLine` and `Order` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use common approach?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{productBean.getList}" var="o">

    <h:column>
        #{o.quantity}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        #{o.produkt.kategoria}
    </h:column>

    ...

    <h:column>
        #{o.produkt.cena}
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

You can access product fields through order object.

### upd

What have you do:

- specify getters and setters to all fields of Order and Product classes
- specify getter and setter to your set of orders
- create this set, put all your orders there
- iterate over it as I showed it before

Comment: it's possible to do that? if yes, how? I must set Product and quantity separately? like `setProduct` and `setQuantity` and link this like `Set<Order> s = new LinkedHashSet<Order>();  s.add(product, quantity);`

Comment: I tried to do this, have: Product bean with getters, setters, Order bean with quantity, product getters, setters and it's does not work